# How to parse [Object HTML] to HTML String

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript variable

inputElem[i]

when I combine it with other string like:

```
var result = inputElem[i]  + '<div>xv</div>';
```

**expected result** :

```
<input type="radio" value="www.abc.com"> 
<div>xv</div>
```

**actually** :

```
[object HTMLInputElement] 
<div>xv</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `inputElem[i]` is a dom element, so the default to string implementation is to blame here.

Looks like you want the wrapping html markup for the element so use [outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.outerHTML)

```
var result = inputElem[i].outerHTML  + '<div>xv</div>';
```

Comment: downvoter, any reason? This is obviously the only right answer at the moment

Answer (score 1):

when, you try to serialize (convert to string) any object, its datatype is what you get as a result

try this:

```
var result = $('<div>').append(inputElem[i]).clone()).html()+ '<div>xv</div>';
```

or

```
 var result = $(inputElem[i]).prop('outerHTML')
```

or with plain javascript, you can simply do `outerHtml` i.e.

```
var result = inputElem[i].outerHTML  + '<div>xv</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you should concatentate the HTML code for input object, not the input object itself.

Use JQuery `html()` function:

`$(inputElem[i]).html() + '<div>xv</div>';`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var result = $(inputElem[i]).html() + '<div>xv</div>';
$('#parentID').html(result);
```